# How Do I Encourage Users Best to Download An Application from a Landing Page?

Tags: website-design, web-app, mobile-web, web, ux-designer

I do consider about the best experience about the getting more conversion rate from a webpage of ours. Is putting phone number field to send the app is best or putting app store buttons? Which one do you prefer? Or any other suggestions?

Comment: By writing a high quality program that the user actually wants to use.

Comment: Is this 'landing page' the homepage of your website or some other page that the user gets redirected to through a partner website?

Comment: Could you expand on your question? There really isn't enough there to help.  Do you have an active community? Do people sign up and act on notices from the company. A little more information would help.

Comment: @Mayo Main purpose of this landing page is giving information about how the application works and of course encourage users to download it. You can't sign up or log in.  My question is actually the putting phone number field to send the app is trendy or not? I put the download buttons above the fold and make them sticky. But I'm not sure. Maybe there are other ways to do that.

Comment: @GülnihalKaraca - give these details in the question. Explain in detail what you're doing. You can also put up screenshots of the alternatives.

Comment: @Mayo, she is asking about the best approaches or the best way to encourage people to be able to solely redirect them to their application. There is no point on community's majority or the idea of the app. It's clear here that there is just a single web page and she wants to clarify or evaluate the possible ways of presenting a downladable action of her own mobile application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the `QR Code` is an alternative hence I prefer "app store buttons" cause they attract me more rather than opening my phone's app to scan or compared to entering my phone number from the keyboard at a basic level instinct.